# find_packages() is not finding all packages in setup.py

Tags: python-2.7

I have project structure as given below

```
 foo
    ├── foo
    │   ├
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── apps
    |         |__ __init.py
    |         |
    |         cfg
    |            |__ __init__.py
    |            |__ __ stocks 
    |                       |__ __ __init__.py
    |                       |__ __ us_google.py
    |                       | __   in_google.py
    |
    |
    |
    ├── README
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── setup.py
```

When I execute find_packages() in setup.py , I do not see

```
foo.apps.cfg.us_google 
foo.apps.cfg.in_google
```

Comment: which command are you using?

Comment: from setuptools import setup, find_packages

Answer (score 0):

Since `us_google.py` and `in_google.py` are in the `stocks` sub-directory, you should look for `foo.apps.cfg.stocks.us_google` and `foo.apps.cfg.stocks.in_google` instead.